# Lync api suddenly stopped sending events without notification

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, ucwa

I use UCWA to get presence events to my application from Lync (Skype for business). The application extends presence subscription when Lync notifies to do so.It works fine, but after some time Lync stops sending me events without any notification.
 I tried to play with presense subscription duration, timeout and "low" parameters for events channel, but that didn't help.

Comment: When you make any GET/POST (such as reportMyActivity) request after you stopped receiving updates, is this request successful?

Comment: Tested that, the request is successful

Comment: Have you tried executing other actions which would trigger different event types (receiving an incoming messagingInvitation, etc) to see if you would see any activity in the event channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making regular reportMyActivity requests solved the issue

Comment: What was the interval that you needed to repeat the reportMyActivity posts on?